# get all IDs of selected checkbox in Yii using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I am trying to get the IDs of all the selected check boxes in yii using JAVASCRIPT. Now i am able to get only the first element ID. Can anyone please suggest the correct code to get all the check box ID.

My View:

```
<input type="button" value="Multiple Host Date Entries" onclick="act();" />

 <div id="grid"></div>
<?php 
//zii.widgets.grid.CGridView  bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView
$obj=$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'id'=>'host_grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'type' => 'striped bordered',

    //'filter'          => $model,
     //'type' => 'striped bordered condensed',
               //'summaryText' => false,
     ////'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'\'changeTRColor()\'',
    //'itemView'=>'_view',
    'columns'=>array(
                                array(
                                'id' => 'selectedIds',
                                'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
                                    'selectableRows'=>2,
                                    'value'          => '$data->host_id',
'checkBoxHtmlOptions' => array('name' => 'idList[]'),
                            ),

                array(            // display 'create_time' using an expression
                            'name'=>'host_name',
                                    'value'=>'$data->host_name',
                ),
                array(
                            'name'=>'host_serviceid',
                            'value'=>'$data->host_serviceid',
                ),
                                array(
                            'name'=>'status',
                            'value'=>'$data->status',
                ),
                array(
                                    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                                    'template'=>'{edit_date}{update}{delete}',
                                    'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'95px'),
                                    'buttons' => array(

                                        'update'=> array(
                                            'label' => 'Update',
                                            'imageUrl' => Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/icons/a.png',
                                            ),

                                        'delete'=> array(
                                            'label' => 'Delete',
                                            'imageUrl' => Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/icons/d.png',
                                            ),

                                        'edit_date' => array( //the name {reply} must be same
                                             'label' => 'Add Date', // text label of the button
                                               'url' => 'Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("NimsoftHostsDetails/View", array("id"=>$data->host_id))', //Your URL According to your wish
                                                  'imageUrl' => Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/icons/m.png',  // image URL of the button. If not set or false, a text link is used, The image must be 16X16 pixels

                                               ),
                                           ),)

                ),

))
        ; 

?>
```

I must select some check boxes and click on multiple host date entries button to go to the specific controller.

My JavaScript:

```
function act()
{
        var idList=$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").serializeArray();
        var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(idList);

       /* Object.keys(idList).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, idList[key]);
    alert(idList[key]);
});*/
        var a=$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").val();
        alert(a); 
        if(idList!="")
              {
                  if(confirm("Add Dates for multiple hosts?"))
                  {
                      var url='<?php echo $this->createUrl('Nimsoft/Date_all',array('idList'=>'val_idList')); ?>';
                      url=url.replace('val_idList',jsonStr);
                      //url=url.replace('val_idList',json_encode(idList));
                      //alert(url);
                      window.open(url);

                      /*$.post('Date_all',idList,function(response)
                      {
                          $.fn.yiiGridView.update("host_grid");
                      });*/
                  }
              }
        else
        {
            alert("Please Select atleast one host");
        }

}
```

I need to pass the IDs to NIMSOFT controller so that I can have a for loop to process each one of those.

Comment: to get ids `var ids = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function () {
    return this.id;
}).get();`

Comment: I want to get the ID of the element.i.e its respective Database ID

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve the [checked column in client side](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCheckBoxColumn#selectableRows-detail) (javasctipt):

```
var idArray = $(gridID).yiiGridView('getChecked', columnID);
 // or
 $.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(gridID);
```

Answer (score 0):

For all checked row ids we use this

```
var id = $.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("your-grid-id", "selectedIds"); // array of seleted id's from grid
```